# STM32 24VDC PWM fan speed control with optocoupler

Tags: mosfet, stm32, fan, duty-cycle

I am using this circuit to control a 24V fan at a frequency of 31kHz (MCU - 72 MHz, Prescaler - 9, Counter period - 255):
[image]

The scheme works. But I want to add an optocoupler to the circuit, I did it like this:
[image]

It's work to. But the fan speed is maximum when duty cycle more than 30%. If I set duty cycle less than 30%, the fan speed decreases. I tried lowering the frequency to 15kHz, 4kHz, 1kHz but it's not help. Perhaps I made the diagram incorrectly?

[IRF7319 Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7319pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f5c82f1b41)

Oscillogram of signal at pin 2 of Q1:
[image]

Power supply:
[image]

Comment: Why the optocoupler in the first place?  Is the fan power supply completely separate (including ground) from the MCU power supply?  Were you seeing interference effects before using the opto?

Comment: @vir Power supplies of MCU and Fan are different, ground are connected between themselves. I want to isolate a microcontroller pin. Do you think the optocoupler is may not be used?

Comment: Can you show a picture (oscilloscope) of what the signal looks like at pin 2 of Q1 for the two schematics you posted?

Comment: @Rodo I add pictures

Comment: _”ground are connected between themselves”_ Please clarify with a schematic. As drawn, they are the same and the optocoupler only adds cost and complexity.

Comment: @winny Hello, I add picture

Comment: Ok, you only have one ground. Forget the optocoupler.

Comment: @winny Why? please explain. If I separate them, then what next?

Comment: The P-FET receives 24 V at the gate in both circuits. This is beyond the specs.

Comment: @Jens Thank you

Comment: Adds nothing of value. If your fan however does not need to be tied to ground, you can cheat with a low side N-MOS buck with high side fan and save cost and complexity.

Comment: @winny Thank you

Comment: Get yourself a bog-standard low Vgsth MOSFET and do it like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330471/low-side-n-mosfet-buck-converter

Comment: @winny Thank you very much for the tip.